# Unmarshalling xml tag with attribute

Tags: xml, go, struct

I am trying to extract some data from XML. The XML tag has an attribute and a value. I'm only interested in the value not attribute. Here's what I'm trying:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type Data struct {
    Info Information `xml:"Reference"`
}

type Information struct {
    Uid  string `xml:"uid,attr"`
    Name string `xml:",chardata"`
}

func main() {
    str := `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Reference uid="123">TestName</Reference>`

    var testData Data

    _ = xml.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &testData)

    fmt.Println("Name is ", testData.Info.Name)
    fmt.Println("uid is ", testData.Info.Uid)

    return
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the steps mentioned in this link? https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmfYeDhGH9bZzihBUDEQbCbTc5k5FZKURMUoUvfmc27BwL/xml/unmarshalling_xml.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your source XML contains a single `<Reference>` element (and **not** an element inside another element), so model it with a simple `struct` (and **not** with a struct inside another struct):

```
type Information struct {
    Uid  string `xml:"uid,attr"`
    Name string `xml:",chardata"`
}
```

And unmarshal into a value of this struct:

```
var testData Information

err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &testData)
fmt.Println(err)

fmt.Println("Name is ", testData.Name)
fmt.Println("uid is ", testData.Uid)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/69C7C96w-RA)):

```
<nil>
Name is  TestName
uid is  123
```